# Send emails with django send_mass_mail

Tags: python, django, email

I am trying to send two  different emails using the django send_mass_mail function. I'm very new to django, and I'm struggling to get it to work. The send-Mail function works fine when I use it, but I want to send different emails to the customer and the site owner when a purchase is made. Any help with this would be amazing! Thanks so much!

```
def _send_confirmation_email(self, order):
    """ Send the user a confirmation email """
    cust_email = order.email
    subject = render_to_string(
        'checkout/confirmation_emails/confirmation_email_subject.txt',
        {'order': order})
    body = render_to_string(
        'checkout/confirmation_emails/confirmation_email_body.txt',
        {'order': order, 'contact_email': settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL})

    subject2 = render_to_string('Order Placed', {'order':order})
    body2 = render_to_string(
        'An order has been placed',
        {'order': order}
    )

    message1 = (
        subject,
        body,
        settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
        [cust_email]
    )

    message2 = (
        subject2,
        body2,
        settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
        ['test@hotmail.com']
    )

    send_mass_mail((message1, message2), fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: What error do you encouter?

Comment: The render_to_string method requires a template_name as a first argument and on your e-mail to test@hotmail.com you are using render_to_string with a string as a first argument. Maybe the error is not the e-mail sending per se, but how you use the render_to_string method. Knowing which error you get would help.

Comment: No error. It just doesn't send the email.

Comment: What is `subject2 = render_to_string('Order Placed', {'order':order})` supposed to do, `'Order placed'` is not a template.

Comment: The simplest way to check if that's the reason would be to define subject2 and body2 as simple strings (no call to render_to_string).

Comment: Ah yes. I think you're right! I'll change that and see what happens. Thank you!

Comment: Hi All,
Thanks so much for all your help. It  turns out that the primary reason the emails weren't sending was an issue with my stripe webhooks, not this code. Thank you all so much for taking the time to help though. I really do appreciate it! Have a great day !